# I keep getting an error when trying to execute my code

Tags: sql, mysqli

```
Declare

    Total integer; 

    i integer;

Begini:= 1;

    total:=1; 

  loop

      total := total * i;

      i := i+1;

    exit when i > 4;

  End loop;

  dbms_output.put_line('total is ' || total);

End;
```

Comment: Hmmm, your question is tagged "mysqli", but the code looks an awful like PL/SQL.  Please tag your question appropriately.  And describe the error you are getting.  And obvious problem is `Begini` in the 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

For start

```
Begini:= 1;

    total:=1;
```

Should be

```
Begin
    i:= 1;
    total:=1;
```